# Entity Framework with only one end connected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have a User

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AddressId {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}
}
```

And an Address class

```
public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So only this is a one to one with only the User having a connection to the other end.

How do I set this up with the fluent API and also is it possible for my generic SaveOrUpdate method to take into account Saving graphs in one go?

```
    public static async Task<T> SaveOrUpdateAsync<T>(this GSCMContext context, T updated) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        if (updated == null)
            return null;

        if (updated.IsPersisted)
        {
            T existing = context.Set<T>().Find(updated.Id);
            if (existing != null)
            {
                context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return existing;
        }

        context.Set<T>().Add(updated);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return updated;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that i can recommend to configure one-to-one relationships:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.Address).WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

Here Address will have its own Identity column, and a User_Id column with FK to User.

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.Address).WithOptionalDependent();
```

Here Address will have its own Identity column, and User will have an Address_Id column with FK to Address.

If you want to tell EF that it should populate the `AddressId` in the User model, you have to configure the relationship as one-to-many:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.Address).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.AddressId);
```

This has the drawback that you have to implement logic to ensure that no more than one Address is related to every user.

Note that configuring a one-to-one relationship as required will lead EF to reuse the Id of the main entity for the dependent entity, i.e. there will be no additional FK column in the table of the dependent entity.